# Defining console in Javascript

Tags: javascript, console

I have a newby question in Javascript. If I call console.log(something) before the following MyInit function is called (in a simple html page), I get an exception because console is not defined. That's ok. But I don't see what the MyInit function does to make it work: It looks like it is defining the log function as something empty that does nothing. How does it get from the definition I provide to the actual console log function that writes to the console?

```
function MyInit()
{
  if (!window.console) console = { log: function () { } };
}
...

<!-- later -->

console.log("OnMouseOver occurred.");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To break down `MyInit()`:

```
if (!window.console)           // If `window` does not have a `console` property
    console = {                // Declare `console` object
        log:                   // Add `log` key
            function () { } }; // ...which is a function which does nothing
```

What this will do is allow `console` and `console.log` to be referenced without any errors being thrown. `console.log("OnMouseOver occurred.");` will simply do nothing on browsers which do not support `window.console` by default.

To show this more clearly I've created a [**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/MN4VJ/) which reverses this method. In this demo we detect if `window.console` *is* supported, and if it is we set override `console.log` to instead equal this empty function. When you run this, you'll see that our `console.log("Hello, world!")` call doesn't log anything to the console, but it equally doesn't throw any errors about either being undefined.

In short, `MyInit()` doesn't *make it work*, it simply creates a `console.log` function which doesn't do anything whatsoever.

Comment: Am I right here (scope is very different from C++/C#):
In globabl scope, look at these two statements:
(A) if (!window.console) window.console = <foo>.
(B) if (!window.console) console = <foo>.
These are the same because the second version sets console on the global scope, which is then a member of window.
But this third version fails:
(C) if (!console) console = <foo>.
because the if statement references an undefined console variable, before it has been assigned anything. In other words, I can test a member of an attribute (window.console) but not an undefined variable.